# Mysql key_buffer_size already 16GB but some fulltext searches are still slow

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, full-text-search, query-performance

I have a query w/ full text search which takes 5 - 10 secs. key_buffer_size is already 16GB.
Table has **15 million records** and has a compound fulltext index on fields: categories and company.

Table Size:
Data Length - 0.9GB
Index Length - 1.1GB

```
    SELECT c.id FROM basetable c 
    WHERE MATCH(c.categories, c.company) 
    AGAINST('+keyword1 +keyword2 +keyword3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    LIMIT 100
```

**Query Results**:
only 88 rows

**Query Status**:
Key_read_requests - 4414336
Key_reads - 1029
Key_write_requests - 12
Key_writes - 2
Handler_read_next - 89

**Query Explain**:
1 | SIMPLE | c | fulltext | categories_company | categories_company | 0 |  | 1 | Using where

**Mysql Global Variables**:
key_buffer_size - **16GB**
key_cache_age_threshold - 300
key_cache_block_size - 1024
key_cache_division_limit - 100
max_heap_table_size - 6gb
tmp_table_size - 6gb

*Fulltext Variables*:
ft_boolean_syntax - **+ -><()~*:""&|**

ft_max_word_len - 20
ft_min_word_len - 2
ft_query_expansion_limit - 20
ft_stopword_file - none

**Server:**
Dual XEONS CPUs
32GB RAM
HD 15kRPM.

Note that not all queries are slow. Some are less than a second; it depends on the keywords used on Full Text search.

Do you have any thoughts on how to improve this?

Comment: Could you post the the `EXPLAIN` output for your query?

Comment: Done. Please see above "Query Explain".

Comment: You state that some searches are slower than others. What are the relative frequencies (how many rows contain the words in the query) of words used in the slower searches compared to the faster queries? Also, you seem to have obfuscated your query. Do you have any other WHERE conditions within your query? Any JOINs?

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'ft%';`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I updated my post; see above. Thanks!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA up

Comment: @redguy From what I observe the fewer the results (less than LIMIT 100) the slower the query gets. Though there are still fast queries with less than 100 results. I don't have any other WHEREs.

Comment: This will sound counter-intuitive, but learned from working with large data with high demand a few years ago that buffers can be **too big**. Searching memory buffers usually does not use the highly-optimized-for-speed techniques employed for disk access as it's unnecessary. Today's memory buffers though are as big as disks of just a few years ago. There's a point of diminishing returns where a **smaller** buffer will actually be faster.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I will try this and update you guys! Thanks!